# New record not appearing in elastic search result

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

Just after creating new record, new record not appearing in listing api although it is getting indexed. New record is appearing when hitting index api again. Using elastic search, implemented through searchkick. Anyone faced this issue?

```
Started POST "/api/v1/pm/projects/4/meetings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-12 13:15:45 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::Pm::MeetingsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"meeting"=>{"name"=>"prj 4 meeting 78", "date"=>"12/10/2018", "start_time"=>"01:30 PM", "end_time"=>"02:00 PM", "url"=>"https://asdf.com", "agenda"=>"prj 4 meeting 78 agenda", "notes"=>"", "members"=>["abc@gmail.com"]}, "project_id"=>"4"}
  AuthenticationToken Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "authentication_tokens".* FROM "authentication_tokens" WHERE "authentication_tokens"."body" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["body", "Eu5fwDmEkLDootjzE3kcUrGi"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "users"."is_approved" = $2 AND "users"."is_archived" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["id", 1], ["is_approved", "t"], ["is_archived", "f"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partner Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."code" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["code", "e-ai"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "meetings" ("name", "date", "start_time", "end_time", "url", "agenda", "notes", "members", "project_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "prj 4 meeting 78"], ["date", "2018-10-12"], ["start_time", "13:30:00"], ["end_time", "14:00:00"], ["url", "https://asdf.com"], ["agenda", "prj 4 meeting 78 agenda"], ["notes", ""], ["members", "{abc@gmail.com}"], ["project_id", 4], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-10-12 07:45:45.133414"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-12 07:45:45.133414"]]
   (10.7ms)  COMMIT
  ***Meeting Store (77.8ms)  {"id":78}***
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (1.81ms)
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 3.5ms | Searchkick: 77.8ms | ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)


Started GET "/api/v1/pm/projects/4/meetings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-12 13:15:45 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::Pm::MeetingsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"4", "meeting"=>{}}
  AuthenticationToken Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "authentication_tokens".* FROM "authentication_tokens" WHERE "authentication_tokens"."body" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["body", "Eu5fwDmEkLDootjzE3kcUrGi"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "users"."is_approved" = $2 AND "users"."is_archived" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["id", 1], ["is_approved", "t"], ["is_archived", "f"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partner Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."code" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["code", "e-ai"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Meeting Search (16.8ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/meetings_development/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":[{"term":{"project_id":4}}]}},"sort":{"cancelled_at":{"order":"asc","unmapped_type":"boolean"},"updated_at":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"long"}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":25,"from":0}'
  Meeting Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE "meetings"."id" IN (77, 75, 76, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (13.02ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 14.4ms | Searchkick: 16.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
```

As you can see in logs meeting with id 78 is getting indexed but not appearing in index api.

Comment: You're probably trying to get the record before ES has a chance to propagate the change out to all of the nodes. ES uses eventual consistency and there's usually a 1 second refresh setting.

Comment: Ok. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use a database with transactions. Search engines are not the best when you depend on reading your own writes.

Answer (score 0):

> Elasticsearch is Near Realtime (NRT) search platform. What this means
>   is there is a slight latency (normally one second) from the time you
>   index a document until the time it becomes searchable. [NRT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/getting-started-concepts.html#_near_realtime_nrt)

If you can use bulk API instead as it is faster in indexing than one record by time.

> For example, the update settings API can be used to dynamically change
>   the index from being more performant for bulk indexing, and then move
>   it to more real time indexing state. Before the bulk indexing is
>   started, use:

```
 PUT /twitter/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "-1"
    }
}
```

check the docs. [refresh_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

and see this discussion [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/long-delay-between-indexing-a-document-and-its-availability-in-search-results/103876/4)